# How to open a file in Java that does not prevent external "Safe Save"?

Tags: java, file

We want to open a file in Java and read its contents.

This file may be updated by an external application using *Safe Save*. That means the file will be externally read and its updated contents will be stored to a new file. Eventually the original file is deleted and the new file is renamed to match the original file's name.

Unfortunately the external process fails during rename (last part of the *Safe Save*) when our Java Application is reading the original file at the same time.
We played with different kind of open modes but could not get a solution that does not fail the external reader.

Is there some way to open a file that does not interfere with external processes accessing the same file? Ideally, whenever an external process moves or deletes the file we would like to get an exception in our Java application. And only there.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve that?

**EDIT:**

Just some clarification regarding the use case:

This an indexer like scenario. We want to index contents of a potentially very large filesystem where 3rd party independent processes can concurrently read from or write to as well. We have no control over the 3rd party processes.
Copying the original file seems like a big overhead and we are not sure if that helps with the original problem as it will probably fail the external reader on a *Safe Save* as well.

*Last but not least:* This should work on Windows and Linux. But we are experiencing this problems on Windows.

Comment: Which operating system is this on, Windows?

Comment: I'm asking because the normal behavior on Unix lets you delete or rename a file while it's open. So I'm guessing you must be on Windows, and need a Windows-specific solution

Comment: @Joni You are correct. The problems occured on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, whether a file can be renamed or deleted while it's open is controlled by the [`FILE_SHARE_DELETE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#syntax) sharing mode flag. This flag should be passed in when the file is opened with the low level [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#syntax) function.

Unfortunately, Java API does not give you control over low level Windows-specific flags. There is an open [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6357433) to have FILE_SHARE_DELETE added by default, but it's unlikely it will be done because of backwards compatibility (some applications may depend on this behavior). the A comment in the report suggests a workaround: instead of `new FileInputStream(file)` use the java.nio API.

```
InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file.toPath());
```

I don't have access to Windows right now to verify that this workaround uses the right sharing mode.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually we tried this as well. It does indeed allow the deletion of a file while it is being read by our Java application. Unfortunately it still fails the external process on the subsequent move operation.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the original file an use this within your Java program, and at the same time keep track of the original file.

Here, this might help you out:

The java.nio.file package provides a file change notification API, called the Watch Service API. This API enables you to register a directory (or directories) with the watch service. When registering, you tell the service which types of events you are interested in: file creation, file deletion, or file modification. When the service detects an event of interest, it is forwarded to the registered process. The registered process has a thread (or a pool of threads) dedicated to watching for any events it has registered for. When an event comes in, it is handled as needed. [Official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Copying the file seems like a big overhead as the filesystem and their contained files can grow TB tall. In addition we are not sure if this would help with the original problem as you would have to open the file for copying as well. That would most likely fail an external delete/move as well, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this only with files, at least not without making additional assumptions. If the processes are not synchronized you will get either (a) errors (b) corrupted data or (c) both. Furthermore, such system will be unstable, prone to race conditions and implementation-specific details. This means that *even if it looks like it's working it will not work correctly always and in each case*.

Depending on your circumstances you might try to use a combination of scehduling (i.e. process A runs every even minute, process B every odd minute), exclusive/shared open flags, range locks, copying files, file change notifiers, retrying on failure etc. If you can somehow ensure that your assumptions are never broken you might end up with something which is "good enough". But all in all, this is a bad engineering practice and should be avoided.

For a proper solution, you need to make *both* processes aware that they are talking to each other. What you have is really a textbook use case for a database. Besides using a database there are plenty of other ways to synchronize access to data - messaging, streams, locks, shared memory etc. Each way has its own benefits and downsides and without knowing more about your specific situation it is impossible to say which would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question. Unfortunately we have no control over the 3rd party processes accessing the filesystem concurrently.